# How to identify a certain object id of an array to change the state of an element in the same object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to identify a specific panel in an array when it is expanded and be able to connect that panel's id to the button, as well as disable the button if no panel is expanded or more than 1 panel is expanded. For whatever reason, it's not taking in the id at all. Also, I am having problems with how to disable the button correctly.

```
export default class WorkoutList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            workoutlist: [
                {
                    id: uuid.v4(),
                    name: 'Leg Day',
                    date: '08/09/19',
                    duration: 60,
                    exerciselist: [
                        {
                            id: uuid.v4(),
                            exerciseName: 'Squats',
                            numberOfSets: 3,
                            reps: 12,
                            weight: 135,
                        },
                        {
                            id: uuid.v4(),
                            exerciseName: 'Leg press',
                            numberOfSets: 3,
                            reps: 10,
                            weight: 150,
                        },
                        {
                            id: uuid.v4(),
                            exerciseName: 'Lunges',
                            numberOfSets: 4,
                            reps: 12,
                        },
                    ],
                    selected: false,
                },
                {
                    id: uuid.v4(),
                    name: 'Arm Day',
                    date: '08/10/19',
                    duration: 90,
                    exerciselist: [
                        {
                            id: uuid.v4(),
                            exerciseName: 'Bench Press',
                            numberOfSets: 5,
                            reps: 5,
                            weight: 225,
                        },
                        {
                            id: uuid.v4(),
                            exerciseName: 'Chest Flies',
                            numberOfSets: 3,
                            reps: 10,
                            weight: 50,
                        },
                        {
                            id: uuid.v4(),
                            exerciseName: 'Tricep Extensions',
                            numberOfSets: 4,
                            reps: 12,
                            weight: 70,
                        },
                    ],
                    selected: false,

                },
                {
                    id: uuid.v4(),
                    name: 'Running',
                    date: '08/11/19',
                    duration: 40,
                    exerciselist: [],
                    selected: false,

                },
            ],
            disabled: false
        }
        this.handleSelectedPanel = this.handleSelectedPanel.bind(this);
        this.handleButton = this.handleButton.bind(this);
    }

    handleSelectedPanel(id) {
        const { workoutlist } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            workoutlist: workoutlist.map(workout => {
                if (workout.id === id) {
                    workout.selected = !workout.selected
                }
                return workout;
            })
        })
    }

    handleButton(){
        const { workoutlist, disabled } = this.state;
        let count = 0;
        workoutlist.map((workout) => {
            if(workout.selected === true) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            return count;
        })
        if (count !== 1) {
            this.setState({
                disabled: true
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                disabled: false
            })
        }
        return disabled;
    }

    render() {
        const { workoutlist } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <CssBaseline />
                <ClientMenuBar title="My Workouts" />
                <div style={styles.workoutlist}>
                    <Paper style={styles.paper} elevation={0}>
                        {workoutlist.map((workout) => (
                            <WorkoutItem
                                key={workout.id}
                                workout={workout}
                                onSelectedPanel={this.handleSelectedPanel}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </Paper>
                    <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        size="small"
                        style={styles.button}
                        disabled={this.handleButton}
                    >
                        Start Workout
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```
export default class WorkoutItem extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleSelectedPanel = this.handleSelectedPanel.bind(this);
    }

    handleSelectedPanel(e) {
        this.props.onSelectedPanel(e.target.id);
    }

    render() {
        const { id, name, date, duration, exerciselist } = this.props.workout;
        return (
            <ExpansionPanel style={styles.panel} id={id} onChange={this.handleSelectedPanel}>
                <ExpansionPanelSummary>
                    <Typography variant="button" style={{ width: "33%" }}>
                        {name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="button" style={{ width: "33%" }}>
                        ({date})
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography align="right" style={{ width: "33%" }}>
                        ~{duration} mins
                    </Typography>
                </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                    <Table size="medium" style={styles.table}>
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell padding="none">Name</TableCell>
                                <TableCell padding="none" align="right"># of sets</TableCell>
                                <TableCell padding="none" align="right">reps</TableCell>
                                <TableCell padding="none" align="right">weight</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {exerciselist.map((exercise) => (
                                <ExerciseList
                                    key={exercise.id}
                                    exercise={exercise}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                    <ExpansionPanelActions disableSpacing style={styles.actionButton}>
                        <Button color="primary" size="small" disableRipple>
                            edit
                        </Button>
                    </ExpansionPanelActions>
                </ExpansionPanelDetails>
            </ExpansionPanel>
        )
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be taking in the id at all, and when i try to disable the button, it throws this error:

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `disabled` of type `function` supplied to `ForwardRef(Button)`, expected `boolean`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you are seeing comes from:

```
<Button
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    size="small"
    style={styles.button}
    disabled={this.handleButton}
>
```

In the error it says a function is passed to disabled which should be a boolean, so change the prop that disabled takes to be that boolean (rather than the function `this.handleButton`).

`e.target.id` doesn't have what you actually want in there (it actually probably isn't a thing). You can use `e.target.value` to get a value out of something like an input where you want to get something information from the DOM node you are working with but in this case the information isn't something entered and actually something that the component already has in its scope (in the props). So instead of:

```
handleSelectedPanel(e) {
    this.props.onSelectedPanel(e.target.id);
}
```

do this

```
handleSelectedPanel(e) {
    this.props.onSelectedPanel(this.props.workout.id);
}
```